# email validation / SwiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created a login page but could not validate it. can you create I don't want them to login without verification. I want e-mail validation and at least 8 characters password.swiftui i am learning new. Unfortunately, I have no information to do this.

```
  @State private var username = ""
  @State private var password = ""
 
  
   var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        
        VStack{//1-1//---
            
            TextField("username", text: $username)
                .frame(width: 300, height:50 , alignment: .center)
                .padding(5)
                .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                  .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).stroke(Color.init( red: 45/255, green: 0/255, blue: 112/255), lineWidth: 1))
            
          TextField("password", text: $password).frame(width: 300, height:50 ,alignment: .center)
                .padding(5)
                .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).stroke(Color.init( red: 45/255, green: 0/255, blue: 112/255), lineWidth: 1))
            
           Button(action: {
                let url = "https:-----------------------"
                let params: [String: String] = ["email": username, "password": password]
                AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON {response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success : print(response.result)
                        
                    case .failure(let error) : print("error\(error)")
                }
                }
                
            
            
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Sign Up")
                    .padding(10)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 30, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
                    .foregroundColor(.init(red: 45/255, green: 0/255, blue: 112/255))
            })
```

[image]

Comment: swiftui i am learning new. Unfortunately, I have no information to do this. sorry @JonathanDavis

Comment: Which type of validation. An email should not empty, max password char etc. that type of validation do you want?

Comment: Yes it would be very good. @RajaKishan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is demo for how to add validation.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct LoginViewV: View {
    
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
            TextField("Password", text: $password)
                .onReceive(Just(password), perform: { _ in
//                    This is for max char. If you want to set limit for character, set here
                    if password.count >= 12 {
                        password = String(password.prefix(12))
                    }
                })
            
            Button(action: {
                
                // Show error message here
                if let errorMessage = self.validView() {
                    print(errorMessage)
                    return
                }
                
                // Call login API here
                /**
                 login API
                 */
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Login")
            })
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    private func validView() -> String? {
        if email.isEmpty {
            return "Email is empty"
        }
        
        if !self.isValidEmail(email) {
            return "Email is invalid"
        }
        
        if password.isEmpty {
            return "Password is empty"
        }
        
        if self.password.count < 8 {
            return "Password should be 8 character long"
        }
        
        // Do same like other validation as per needed
        
        return nil
    }
    
    private func isValidEmail(_ email: String) -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
        let emailPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailPred.evaluate(with: email)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest, but I encountered an error. @RajaKishan

Comment: Check my updated answer. You need to ```import Combine```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this line is not changing password. this is for set limitation, suppose I want to set max character limit for any field like max 12 char then, this give me only first 12 character of the starting string and drop all the char after 12 char. no matter user type or not. This is optional. So how you think for change ?

Comment: I want one more thing, can you create a text field for password verification? Let them log in when the passwords are the same. @RajaKishan

Comment: @metaflor22 This is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Are you talking about confirming the password? for this, you need to just compare two password var. And for others, you need to add your own logic this is just an example.